# How to setup NiFi cluster using 3 machines (1 Manager & 2 nodes) using external zookeeper

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I am trying to setup a NiFi cluster with 3 machines (1 Manager & 2 nodes) on different machines using external zookeeper.

I have changed following things in 
**nifi.properties**

> nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2181
>   nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false

I have created **zoo.cfg** file in Zookeeper/conf folder which contains

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/Data/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2888:3888
```

and created **myid** file in **dataDir=/home/Data/zookeeper/** location which contains 1.

I have followed almost all the articles available on internet but could not be able to setup the cluster successfully.

on starting nifi services it is not showing any cluster. I have checked that my zookeeper is running and using jps :

```
3890 QuorumPeerMain
3989 RunNiFi
4006 NiFi
6813 Jps
```

How can I setup NiFi cluster for 3 machines (1 Manager and 2 Nodes) on different machines using external zookeeper.

Comment: This question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

Important things to check:
nifi.properties:

> nifi.cluster.is.node=true
>
> nifi.cluster.node.address={hostname}

is your zookeeper cluster up?

All the other things you mentioned sound correct.

Comment: yes, I have already set that to **true**...and zookeeper cluster is up which can be seen using jps.

Comment: @Deepanshu could you share your nifi.propeties file?

Comment: it is showing cluster in menu now, but it is showing 4 rows though I have set up only 2 nodes. And, it is showing as **localhost:8080**, instead of the IP Address.

Comment: That's because you need to set the host property with your hostname. It is crucial!

Comment: Okay, so I have to modify the content of **/etc/hosts** file?

Comment: @Deepanshu no! I've added the setting to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188806/discussion-between-deepanshu-and-ben-yaakobi).